# Bash script: Use variable in sed to delete all but the last "x" lines of a file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

I'm using the following bash script to delete all but the last 'x' lines in a log file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to  write to the log file every minute  and delete all but the last 
# set time in hours

echo `date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H\%M\%S`,`/home/pi/temp/temp` >> /home/pi/temp/temp.log

HOURS="12"                      #Nr of hours in the log
LINES=$(( $HOURS * 60 + 1 ))    #Nr of minutes/lines in the log

echo $LINES                     #Included just for testing if i'm getting the desired amount of lines

sed -e :a -e '$q;N;$LINES,$D;ba' temp.log >temp1.log ;mv temp1.log  temp.log
```

I substituted the $LINES for its value (12 hours), 721 and the script is working as a cron task, runs every minute, without errors, so i'm sure the error is in the part that includes the variable in the sed.

Also, I just copied this from some website, if someone could be kind enough to explain me what is going on in the sed command, maybe i'd be able to figure out the mistake myself.

This is the error:

> `sed: -e expression #2, char 8: extra characters after command.`

Also, it deletes all the lines in the file.

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is? What excatly is not working? What is the outcome of your script which is not as expected?

Comment: just edited to include the error, sorry i forgot to post it earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the variables out of single quotes:

```
sed -e :a -e '$q;N;'"$LINES"',$D;ba'
```

Other notes:

- Get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS variable names. One day you'll write PATH=/tmp and then wonder why your script is broken.
- `%` is not a special character for the shell, you don't need to escape it: `date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`
- use `$(...)` instead of backticks: easier to see and way easier to nest.
- sed can edit a file in-place, you don't need to write to a temp file and `mv` it:

  ```
  sed -i -e :a -e '$q;N;'"$LINES"',$D;ba'
  ```
- this is very similar to [this stackoverflow answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157570/how-do-i-print-all-but-the-nth-to-last-line-in-sed/157571#157571) that is well documented. Read that for insight.

Comment: Thanks, will try that ;) as for the caps thing, i really just did that because i saw online on a bash scripting beginners guide, if it wasnt' for that guide i wouldn't have used, but i will change that, thanks :)

P.S.: Also, about the editing a file in place, so i just put the filename after the sed command and it will edit it in place? like sed -i -e :a -e '$q;N;'"$LINES"',$D;ba' temp.log ?

Comment: that's right. .

Answer (score 4):

I know this is not the answer you wanted since it does not relates to sed but you can use `tail` in the same way you want, just doing:

> `tail -n <lines> <file> > <new_file>`
>
> `mv new_file file`

Comment: yeah, thanks, i know this, i'm just using sed because i've read somewhere that tail is slower... anyway, if i use tail, how do i include the variable in the lines? just do $LINES ?

Comment: Yes, that would do it.

Comment: i'll keep sed for now since i have that editing the actual file instead of having to create a new and mv it to the 1st file name thing working :)